# CarouselView swiping is Buggy

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I'm relatively new to Xamarin Forms.  I'm trying to have a view that allows me to swipe left/right between different pages with a page indicator at the bottom.  I'm using `CarouselView`, as suggested by the internet, and it seems to work.  But, the selected page is very buggy.  Sometimes, swiping to the next page causes it to snap back to the previous page.  Sometimes, it stays on the current page.  Sometimes, it works correctly.  I observe the same behavior on both Android and UWP.  Although, it appears to be a little worse in UWP than Android.

It seems the index for the current page is getting mixed up somehow.  Here is my XAML:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout>

            <CarouselView x:Name="Pages" IndicatorView="{x:Reference ActivePageIndicator}">

                <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                        <views:TroubleshootingPage />
                        <views:StatusPage />
                        <views:ContactInfoPage />
                    </x:Array>
                </CarouselView.ItemsSource>

                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

            </CarouselView>

            <IndicatorView
                x:Name="ActivePageIndicator"
                IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="Green"
                IndicatorSize="16"
                IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Margin="4"
                />

        </StackLayout>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I've tried using different types of views in the `ItemsSource` list.  But, I still get the same effect.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Something I'm missing?  A bug in `CarouselView`?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the sample in the official document? In addition, you can try to update the version of the xamarin.forms with the nuget package manager.

Comment: I updated to the latest stable version in the nuget package manager and still have the same result.  However, I added a line of code to the constructor which sets the CurrentItem in the ```CarouselView``` to the first item in the list.  Normally it's null.  This seemed to fix it for the most part.  It still freaks out if you scroll past the last page.  I would expect it to stay on the last page if you try to scroll past it, but it keeps going and ends up doing the weird behavior again until I scroll all the way back to the first page.

Comment: Did you try to add a Scrolled event to set the index by yourself? You can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling#detect-scrolling).

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.  I have put this off to figure out another time.  One of the solutions I was going to look into was controlling the index myself.